# Как объединить данные с 2 листов в Гугл таблицах?

Tags: sql, google-spreadsheet

Требуется вывести в отдельный лист данные из столба "A", "Лист1" и столбца "B",  "Лист2". Возможно ли сделать это через sql-запрос, конкатенирующий данные из разных листов и столбцов?

Comment: "Выделить, скопировать, вставить" не помогает?

Comment: нет. мне надо чтобы динамически менялись данные

Answer (score 1):

Все достаточно просто. Можно выполнить задачу с помощью:
**1)** Вставить первую формулу в "Лист3" в нужную ячейку, допустим A1, вторую в B1, (или в другую таблицу заменив "Ключ таблицы" на ссылку, скопировав ее в "НАСТРОЙКИ ДОСТУПА"). 
При данном способе вставки, редактирование данных невозможно, если оно того не требует, то подойдет. Если требует см способ 2.

`=IMPORTRANGE ("Ключ таблицы";"Лист1!A1:А")`

`=IMPORTRANGE ("Ключ таблицы";"Лист2!B1:B")`

**2)** Вставить в "Лист3" в ячейку, допустим С1 и D1. Далее выделяем диапазон столбцов C1 и D1, /правой кнопкой мыши/, \Сгруппировать столбцы C, D (Чтобы не мешали визуальному просмотру).

`=IMPORTRANGE ("Ключ таблицы";"Лист1!A1:А")`

`=IMPORTRANGE ("Ключ таблицы";"Лист2!B1:B")`

Далее в ячейках A1 и B1 "Лист3" Вставляем SQL запросы

```
=query(Лист3!C1:С;"select * limit 1000")
```

`=query(Лист3!D1:D;"select * limit 1000")`

Где: "C1:D" - диапазон запроса, "*" - выдать все поля. "limit1000" - ограничить вывод 1000 полей. Данный способ так же рассматривается без участия функции "=IMPORTRANGE". Но не работает если данные нужно собирать из других таблиц.

**Важно.** Используя SQL запросы для дальнейшего редактирования заполните первую строку названиями полей (пр.: A1=ID, B1=TEXT)  т.к. редактировать первую ячейку с SQL запросом так же будет невозможно.

Для удобства и читабельности так же переместите от левого угла таблицы жирную серую полосу (над номером стоки "1") вниз (до номера строки "2").

Говоря о конкатенации, используй: 
`=СЦЕПИТЬ(строка_1; строка_2)`

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать функцию `FLATTEN()` в сочетании с `FILTER()`.

Не уверен, что эта функция была в 2018 году. Мой ответ для тех, кто попадет на страницу вопроса по поиску, авось ему пригодится.

Формула такая:

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN('Лист1'!A1:A;'Лист2'!A1:A);FLATTEN('Лист1'!A1:A;'Лист2'!A1:A)<>"")
```

[Пример в файле](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NPLmPpFY4u-0Jcunv67WT3NasnUMBP-BMVHtXsjh-kk/edit?usp=sharing)